# Delete inner word in helix editor

Tags: editor, text-editor, helix-editor

I am used to using `diw` in vim to delete a word when the curser is in the middle of the word.
How can I do the same in helix editor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

miwd

Helix has that highlight first approach, so basically all the motions are the same but relative to that/those selected token/s.

Answer (score 2):

bed: select back to word start, select until word end, delete

Alt-up or Alt-o, d: expand selection (scope), then delete

(ebd works the same as bed)

Answer (score 1):

open your helix editor (e.g ~/.config/helix/config.toml)

and add some config:

[key.normal]
"d"."i"."w" = [
"move_char_right", "move_prev_word_start", "move_next_word_end",
"yank_main_selection_to_clipboard", "delete_selection_noyank", ]

and save/apply:
:w
:config-reload

my helix key setting:
https://github.com/TinyProbe/config_tinyprobe/blob/master/config.toml